# sqlite database

Tags: sqlite

I want to save object to SQLite database. Can any any one explain is it possible? if possible, then how? I am so eager to know that, please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of object? What language and platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What sort of object? What client language are you using? You could try to serialize the object through JSON or XML and then store the text.

Comment: store the object of bytearray.i am using java for blackberry application.

Comment: I would just convert the bytearray into a string and store that.